# How can I apply https to flask via using Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM)

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, https

I'm using the flask to serve my application. I have received the certificate from AWS Amazon Certificate Manager, but it is not correctly applied to my flask app. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Certificate Manager does not allow the created certificates to be exported. So the best way to achieve what you are trying to to, is create an [ELB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancer-getting-started.html) in front of your Flask app and then using the certificate on that.

You can do this with either the [Classic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html) or the [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html).

If you insist on running it within the Flask instance itself, then something like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is likely a better solution.